# Alexa Flask Ask Yes / No response handling

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

I am trying to create a simple Alexa skill using Flask Ask in python.

I have an **intent called "SearchIntent" with a "searchterm" slot** and the python code looks something like this:

```
@ask.intent("SearchIntent")
def SearchIntent(searchterm):
    resList = []
    searchterm = searchterm.lower()

    for item in somelist:
        if item.find(searchterm) != -1:
            resList.append(item)
    
            
    return question("I Found " + str(len(resList)) + ", Do you want me to list them all?")
```

I want to check if the response from the user, if he says "Yes" than read all the results:

```
return statement('\n'.join(resList))
```

and if the user says no, to perform some other action

something like:

```
...

    return question("I Found " + str(len(resList)) + ", Do you want me to list them all?")

if "return question" == "yes":
   do something
else:
   do something else
```

I don't want to create the search function again in a YesIntent, Is it possible to do something like this within the same function?

Comment: How about setting appropriate session attributes and based on them you give the appropriate message in yes/no intent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible in the suggested way using flask ask. After you call `return`, you leave your SearchIntent() function and have no way to check the answer or run additional code.
However, you can still make it work: after the user answers your question a new intent is sent and flask-ask calls the according function. By using session attributes, as suggested by @user3872094, you can process your `searchterm` in this new function. Session attributes are used to preserve user input during a session between different intent requests.
Check this minimal example:

```
@ask.intent("SearchIntent")
def SearchIntent(searchterm):
    session.attributes['term'] = searchterm
    return question("I understood {}. Is that correct?".format(searchterm))

@ask.intent('AMAZON.YesIntent')
def yes_intent():
    term = session.attributes['term'] 
    return statement("Ok. So your word really was {}.".format(term))

@ask.intent('AMAZON.NoIntent')
def no_intent():    
    return statement("I am sorry I got it wrong.")
```

Add the Amazon Yes and No intents to your intent_schema:

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
        "intent": "SearchIntent",
        "slots": [{
            "name": "searchterm",
            "type": "AMAZON.LITERAL"
        }]
        },{
            "intent": "AMAZON.NoIntent"
        }, {
            "intent": "AMAZON.YesIntent"
        }      
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it was very helpfull